# Finding minimum value in a collection

Tags: java, collections, iterator, minimum

To find the minimum value in a collection of given types, what would I need to set "value" to in order to compare it to "min"? Value should be the next element in the collection and it should iterate until the collection is fully read through.

```
public <T> T min(Collection<T> c, Comparator<T> comp) {
if ((c == null) || (comp == null)) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }

  if (c.isEmpty() == true) {
     throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }

  Iterator itr = c.iterator(); 
  T min = (T)itr.next();
  T value = ;
  while (itr.hasNext()) {   
     if (comp.compare(min, value) < 0) { 
        min = value;  
     }
  }
  return min;
```

}

Comment: Have you seen `Collections#min`?

Comment: It is for a school assignment, and I cannot import the collections package.

Comment: Don't use rawtypes and cast to `T`, use `Iterator<T>` that gives you a `T` without casting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
 Iterator itr = c.iterator(); 
 T min = (T)itr.next();
 T value;
 while (itr.hasNext()) { 
      value=(T)itr.next();
      if (comp.compare(min, value) < 0) { 
         min = value;  
      }
 }
```

Comment: When you declare T as <T extends Comparable<T>> then you don't need an additional Comparator argument. Instead you can use min.compareTo(value). Anyway, it's easier to use java.util.Collections.min(...) instead if possible.